# How to steep but separate leaves in a teapot without a mesh strainer?

Tags: food, substitute-tool, kitchen, drinks

[My metal mesh tea strainer rusted so I discarded it](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/49585), but I have failed to find a replacement  strainer because this teapot was likely purchased overseas.

In a teapot, how else can I filter the tea leaves steeped in hot water, from the resultant liquid that is poured and sipped? Woefully, this teapot can't be equipeed with a filter at the spout.

Comment: Although not the best method, this should not need any other equipment: [**Decantation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decantation) followed by a careful pour? I used to do that with coffee all the time. The downside (upside for some) is that sedimentation for coffee for one person took up to 6 minutes=strong coffee. The only thing I am skeptical about is whether your tea leaves are too buoyant. I know that twinnings isn't and sediments to the bottom in 5-6 minutes (again, strong tea!) Any comments on how to force/accelerate sedimentation?

Answer (score 5):

you can make your own tea bags by using a square of cheese cloth or muslin folded over a few times, place the loose tea in it, use butcher's twine to tie the bag up and there you go! you can even untie the twine and re-use the cloth for other bags.  What's good about this hack is that you can make tea bags of any size depending on how large you cut the cloth. so you can make single serving ones for just a cup or you can make larger ones for when you want an entire pot of tea.

If you don't have cheese cloth/muslin I suppose you could use another fabric but you really want something thin so that the water can seep in and mix with the tea and also to let flavor out of the bag and into the tea.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the cheesecloth idea... coffee filters can also be used to make a pouch for a bundle of leaves.

I would caution to be careful of using fabrics or materials that are not food-safe as they may contain chemicals that will leach right into the tea along with the good stuff.

Comment: Yes although a fix, this might lead to a change in the flavor of the tea? Coffee filters are known to sap out all the essential oils (flavors) from coffee. Who's to say that they won't do the same to tea. `+1` on suggesting use of food safe material.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at a tea strainer on Google something immediately came to my mind, however it will involve perhaps demolishing a sieve.

If you happen to have an old sieve that you are willing to modify somewhat then that's great - carry on reading.

**Step one:**
Remove the old metal mesh from your old strainer, some wire cutters would work on a stronger metal but scissors may work or you may even be able to push the metal out.

**Step two:**
Remove the metal mesh from your sieve and cut out a square / circle or whatever of the material the same or a similar size to the piece that you have just removed from the old strainer.

**Step three:**
Insert newly made mesh into the old casing and seal it down with some glue - leave to dry for a day to make sure that it is fully cured and won't get into your beverage.

**Step four:**
You should now have a makeshift tea strainer thing - probably won't be as fine a mesh than the original but should suffice for most tea leaves.

*Note, if you do not want to use the old casing you can probably makeshift your own out of paper clips or metal wire and shaping them into whatever shape you want it and then making a cage like thing with the sieve mesh.*

Another method I found when looking for a different solution to your problem is to [use some tin foil](http://snappyliving.com/how-to-make-a-tea-strainer-out-of-tin-foil/). I'll summarize the contents of the link I have attached:

- Cut a foot square of tin foil
- Fold in half twice so it is now a quarter of the original size
- Pour tea leaves into the center
- Bring corners together above the leaves and twist them together making a sort of stick - you'll end up with what looks like a tin foil ball on the end of a tin foil stick
- When you are ready to brew your tea, poke some small holes in the tin foil ball with a cocktail stick or similar and then brew in the normal way for the normal amount of time!

Here is what it should sort of look like:
[image]

Good luck.

Comment: As the other question was marked as duplicate thought I would carry this answer over too

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a strainer built into your teapot, use an external strainer. Allow the hot water and loose tea leaves to hang out in your pot, then pour through the strainer into your cup.
[image]

This one costs $4 Cdn on amazon.ca. I'm sure you can find plenty in that price range. Slightly more expensive ones come with a little bowl to set them down in so as not to dribble on a counter.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to keep the tea warm for a while, use the strainer to strain the whole potful into another teapot or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a french press for coffee works very well with this. You don't have to press the leaves down at first if you feel like letting them float for longer. Then it's up to you when you want to press the leaves down. It's also extremely easy to clean, and you don't need to make special tea bags or anything that will need to be thrown away after each use.

Answer (score -1):

Buy ordinary, empty tea bags? (e.g. [http://www.amazon.com/T-Sac-Filter-Disposable-Infuser-Capacity/dp/B001BLCIN4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001BLCIN4))

Comment: not really a hack but it definitely works